# Issue getting different elements in nav bar to align vertically

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I made several changes to a navigation bar that I had. Since the changes, I cannot get the red "Request Quote" button to vertically align in the middle to line up with the other items in the nav.

What I changed was wrapping the link around the list item so that the whole space would be clickable for the mobile version. Previously, the html was like:

```
<li><a href="">LEARN</a></li>
```

and I would use `#nav-list li a` to call the elements because I didn't assign a class at that point.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? I do not want to use `position: absolute` if possible.

```css
nav {
 background: #FFF;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#nav-pop {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 25px;
 transition: ease 0.5s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
}
#nav-pop.active {
 opacity: 1;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 background: #2f2f2f;
 right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 z-index: 999999;
 transition: ease 0.6s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
 transform: translateX(0);-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.navItem {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 17px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.navItem:first-child {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.navItem:last-child {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.navItem, #serviceClick {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 color: #747678;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 vertical-align: top;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.navItem:after, #serviceClick:after {
 content: '';
    display: block;
 width: 0;
 margin-top: 6px;
 background: #b82222;
 height: 2px;
 transition: width .3s;
}
.navItem:hover, #serviceClick:hover {
 color: #4b4b4b;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.navItem:hover:after, #serviceClick:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}
.navInverse {
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #b82222;
 background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #b82222, #a51e1e);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.navInverse:hover {
 background: #b82222;
 background: #FFF;
 color: #b82222;
}
.navInverse:after {
 content: '';
    display: none;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 transition: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <div id="nav-pop">
  <ul id="nav-list">
   <a href="" class="navItem"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
   <li id="serviceClick" class="navItem">SOLUTIONS</li>
   <a href="" class="navItem"><li>LEARN</li></a>
   <a href="" class="navItem"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
   <a href="" class="navInverse navItem" id="quoteButton"><li>REQUEST QUOTE</li></a>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A revised answer of my previous explantaion, just remove the margin-top in `nav-pop` and the add:

```
#nav-list {

display: flex;
align-items: center;

}
```

See snippet for finished output:

```css
nav {
 background: #FFF;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav-list {

display: flex;
align-items: center;

}
 
#nav-pop {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 15px;
 transition: ease 0.5s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
}
#nav-pop.active {
 opacity: 1;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 background: #2f2f2f;
 right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 z-index: 999999;
 transition: ease 0.6s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
 transform: translateX(0);-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.navItem {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 17px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.navItem:first-child {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.navItem:last-child {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.navItem, #serviceClick {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 color: #747678;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 vertical-align: top;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.navItem:after, #serviceClick:after {
 content: '';
    display: block;
 width: 0;
 margin-top: 6px;
 background: #b82222;
 height: 2px;
 transition: width .3s;
}
.navItem:hover, #serviceClick:hover {
 color: #4b4b4b;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.navItem:hover:after, #serviceClick:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}
.navInverse {
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #b82222;
 background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #b82222, #a51e1e);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.navInverse:hover {
 background: #b82222;
 background: #FFF;
 color: #b82222;
}
.navInverse:after {
 content: '';
    display: none;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 transition: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <div id="nav-pop">
  <ul id="nav-list">
   <a href="" class="navItem"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
   <li id="serviceClick" class="navItem">SOLUTIONS</li>
   <a href="" class="navItem"><li>LEARN</li></a>
   <a href="" class="navItem"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
   <a href="" class="navInverse navItem" id="quoteButton"><li>REQUEST QUOTE</li></a>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @paul Hi, I have edited the answer, what you need is on the #nav-pop id to add margin-top: 15px; (reduce the original by 10px); ---> this is in my new answer (snippet).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Keep li as child  of ul not anchor.

Removed the top margin on nav-pop.

Added display: flex and align-items: center on nav-list.

Reduced the after element's margin to zero.

```css
nav {
  background: #FFF;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav-pop {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5%;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
}

#nav-pop.active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background: #2f2f2f;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  transition: ease 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.navItem {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 17px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navItem:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.navItem:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.navItem,
#serviceClick {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
  color: #747678;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navItem:after,
#serviceClick:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: #b82222;
  height: 2px;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.navItem:hover,
#serviceClick:hover {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}

.navItem:hover:after,
#serviceClick:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.navInverse {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #b82222;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #b82222, #a51e1e);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navInverse:hover {
  background: #b82222;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #b82222;
}

.navInverse:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  transition: none;
}

 #nav-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navItem a {
  padding: 24px 12px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav-pop">
    <ul id="nav-list">
      <li href="" class="navItem"><a>ABOUT</a></li>
      <li id="serviceClick" class="navItem">SOLUTIONS</li>
      <li href="" class="navItem"><a>LEARN</a></li>
      <li href="" class="navItem"><a>CONTACT</a></li>
      <li href="" class="navInverse navItem" id="quoteButton"><a>REQUEST QUOTE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I switched all of this in the first place so that the anchor nested the list item. I need the entire width to be clickable. Not just the list wording.

Comment: Check my updated snippet ..I added this style  .navItem a {
  padding: 24px 12px;
} It will allow a bigger area served as anchor without messing up the html

Answer (score 0):

To get a full alignment on your `navbar` I removed the `margin-top` from the `#nav-pop id` it wasn't necessary. Then changed the `nav-list` id (because it's the container) by adding the following:

```
#nav-list {

display: flex;
align-items: center; 

}
```

Giving me the desired display you're after:

[image]

Comment: When I do this, the list items go to the very top.

Comment: @paul , see my snippet (new answer) this is how it looks on my monitor, they're not pushed to the top either. Hope this new answer example helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I notice is that your ul `#nav-list` has a margin-top that may be affecting your alignment, but the most important issue is that the height of `#quoteButton` does not match the line-height of the rest of your links (because there is none set). This will cause `vertical-align: middle` to not work correctly as the elements are not the same heights.

When I set the line-height of each `<li>` to 44px they align perfectly.  To me, the answer suggested by @billy.farroll is not sufficient as the button text does not align with the `<li>`s.